# Как лучше организовать модель корзины в mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Помимо модели корзины, есть еще модель products и модель user. У меня есть два варианта организации:
1) Корзина хранит в себе только ID продуктов и будет стучаться к коллекции products
2) Корзина хранит в себе всю информацию о продуктов, также как и products(title, price, rest)

Я думаю, что первый вариант лучше, но верно ли я предполагаю?
И тогда, при первом варианте, frontend сначала сделает запрос к cart и, получив ID, сделает запрос к products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант однозначно лучше, хотя бы потому, что иначе помимо дублирования информации, вам еще придется отслеживать изменения для всех товаров, чтобы обновлять информацию у пользователях в корзинах.

**Предположим, что у вас следующие сущности:**

> **Card:**
>
> _id: objectId
>   products: Array(ObjectId[product])

> **Product:**
>
> _id: objectId
>   name: string
>  description: string
>  price: number

Тогда вот запрос для получения информации из корзины, включая продукты:

```
db.getCollection('card').aggregate([{
    $lookup:
       {
         from: "product",
         localField: "products",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "products"
       }
}]);
```

PS. В mongoose, к примеру, все тоже самое можно сделать через [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!